# どうか, どうにか, どうかして - differences?

Tags: grammar

I was just wondering what the essential differences are between these and how I would use them in everyday speech.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You've got 3 words here that *look* similar but in meaning and use are really pretty distinct.

どうか is used to make very polite requests. It has kind of a strong meaning so I don't think it's something that comes up too often in your day to day life. It can have a kind of sense of desperation to it, like begging a doctor to save someone's life or begging someone not to take you to court or something like that, or it can also just be affixed to polite requests. (どうか助けてください！）
[(alc for reference)](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B&ref=sa)

どうにか expresses the idea of "somehow or other," like you're not really sure how or why it worked, or you didn't think it would. Basically things just weren't that great but some way or another you managed to pull through. (難しかったが、どうにか成功しました) [(alc for reference)](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8B)

どうかして kind of borrows from どうか but only insofar as it describes doing "something." どうかして just means that you want to do something, somehow. In fact it doesn't really matter how, you just want to make it happen. It may be more useful to think of it as a hypothetical sort of situation like in the example below, like "if by chance *something* were to happen." Examples on alc seem to show this having a kind of poetic "if only" kind of feel to it, like this:

> どうかして夢にみたことをのこらず、あくる日目がさめてもおぼえていられたらいいだろう。
>
> If only to-morrow on awaking, I could again call all to mind so vividly!

[(alc for reference)](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%20-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%20-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%20-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BE)

This is not to be confused with どうかしている, which is an expression that means you've gone crazy or that there's something wrong with something/someone in the not thinking straight sort of sense.

Comment: Reasoning for the downvote? Did I get something wrong?

Comment: ^ Hmm..? I don't see anything wrong with your post either... I think maybe you could add "どうかしてくれ!" "どうにかしてくれ!" ("Do something!", like "なんとかしてくれ!") ?? ...I don't really see what's confusing OP though.

Comment: @ssb - I didn't down vote you, thank you for the answer!  Judging from the example you gave, I am guessing I would almost never use or come in contact with どうかして in everyday use, correct?
- どうかしている <- Do you have an example for this?

Comment: @Chocolate - All those three sentences you wrote mean "Do something!" ?  So, どうか, どうにか, and なんとか are, in fact, interchangeable as long as the meaning is 'something'?

Comment: @Mike I don't hear it used really, and it seems on alc like it doesn't have a lot of use. So I'd say it's not *really* commonly used, but you might still come across it in literary stuff or more formal writing. Might be better asking a native how often it comes up, but for now just be ready to understand it and don't worry about using it.

Comment: @Mike Yes どうかしてくれ, どうにかしてくれ and なんとかしてくれ can be used to mean "Do something!" but どうかしてくれ is quite colloquial (or sloppy?) so I think more grammatically/ correctly it should be どうにかしてくれ or なんとかしてくれ. I don't think they're always interchangeable though, even when you mean to say "something", eg. You can say どうかしたんですか but not どうにかしたんですか/なんとかしたんですか to mean "Something wrong?/What's wrong?"

Comment: どうかして is more used in どうかしてる, eg http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B　https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiV-gj1NiT4

Comment: BTW we also have どうにかして(なんとかして) http://ja.websaru.info/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6.html